# SSRS hard coding the order of a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I have an SSRS matrix that draws strings out of my DB. The strings are timeslots: 7:00-8:00pm, 8:00-9:00pm etc. I have the matrix displaying all of the data required, but the order seems to be locked to alphabetical, so 10:00-11:00am displays after 1:00-2:00pm, but before 8:00-9:00am, leading to a lot of visual confusion once they are all displayed on top of each other.

Is there a way to sort the strings differently? Or a way to hard code the order? Thanks!

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and drawing off a Microsoft SSMS based DB.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this assuming that you don't want to reformat your time slot strings, is to have 2 sort expressions. Replace your current sort expression with these.

The first would be

```
=Instr(Fields!myTimeSlotDField.Value, ":")
```

The second would simply be your time slot field

```
=Fields!myTimeSlotDField.Value
```

The first expression will return `2` for any time slots that only have a single number in front of the colon and return `3` where there are two numbers before the colon. Once those are sorted, your second sort will sort the individual timeslots.